# how to remove any changes made by compiz?

Tags: unity, compiz

I had ubuntu 14.04 with unity desktop. Then i downloaded and used compiz but messed up and now unity desktop is not usable. I dont see the menu on top or the panel on left side. Neither is the CLI available after pressing `Ctrl+Alt+t`.

However I can still access the CLI by pressing `Ctrl+Alt+F1`. Now, how can I undo any changes that compiz had applied, so that the desktop will be usable again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should reset all of your changes to Compiz/Unity:

1. Install dconf-tools: `sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`
2. Reset Compiz and Unity: `dconf reset -f /org/compiz/`
3. Reset Unity: `setsid unity`

Comment: it wasnt allowing me to accept before coz i had to wait for some mminimum number of minutes before accepting an answer. But i cannot see any `/org` directory now. Was that directory removed ?

Comment: did you include the slash at the end of `/org/compiz/`?

Comment: yes.  for ex: if i do `$ cd /org` it says no directory. Same for `$ cd /org/compiz/`

Comment: I'm honestly not sure. `/org` isn't part of the [FHS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard). There's no mention of it in `man hier` either. The directory doesn't exist on my system either. Did you have some files in that directory that you're worried about? Does everything else seem to be working fine?

Comment: yeah.. everything seems fine .. and no i did not have anything in that directory, so no worries. .. i had never seen a  `/org` directory before either, so I was just wondering.

Answer (score 1):

Delete those directories and login again:

```
rm  -rf ~/.compiz-1 

rm -rf ~/.config/compiz-1
```